# AxisFault: (500)Internal Server Error

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, axis

how to know what does axis 500 error mean ?? can I have a specific error returned showing me where is the problem. Am deploying my application using axis

Answer (score 1):

500 means internal server error. Look in the server log. If you don't have access to the server log, turn on debug logging in the axis client  or use tcpdumb or wireshark, you usually get a more detailed error message this way.